# FLASHBACK Command as unknown command Oracle 11gR2 Express Edition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I created a table in Oracle 11gR2 Database. I have a user named *store* which is granted roles *connect* and *resource*. The above mentioned table is created by user *store*. Now I dropped the table with command 
    **DROP TABLE my_table;**
Now, I want to recover that deleted table, with FLASHBACK command as
     **FLASHBACK TABLE BIN$yrMKlZaVMhfgNAgAIMenRA==$0 TO BEFORE DROP;**
But it says error as "FLASHBACK COMMAND NOT FOUND". 
Is flashback feature removed in Oracle 11g ?

Comment: [This](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/product-editions-066501.html) suggests flashback table/database isn't available for Express Edition, but refers to 10g. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/backrest.htm#CHDICDDH) suggests it can be done from SQL Developer though.

Comment: What client are you using to issue the command?  If you haven't already, please try it in SQLPlus (preferably, the same version as the database).

Comment: I am using SQL Plus 8.0 Editor for issuing command.

Comment: Are you using XE?  What exact version and Edition are you using?  Assuming you are using 8i client, that's a problem.  Upgrade to the latest client version.

Comment: Yeah,  You are right. The problem was with 8i client. Instead it was working with SQL Developer. Thanks RMAN Express.